# Algebra problem solve for a,b,c and d?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, radicals

Can anyone find the values of these integers: a,b,c and d?

$$1+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{6} = \sqrt{a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt{c+\sqrt{d}}}}$$

a+b+c+d = ?

Thank you.

Comment: Square both sides, subtract $a$, square again, subtract $b$, square, subtract $c$, square. You now have an expression involving the square roots of 2, 3, and 6, and you want the coefficients of those square roots to be zero. This gives you equations to solve for $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$F=1+\sqrt2+\sqrt3+\sqrt6=(1+\sqrt2)(1+\sqrt3)$$

$$F^2=a+\sqrt{b+\sqrt{c+\sqrt d}}$$

Squaring we get $$F^2=(1+\sqrt2)^2(1+\sqrt3)^2=(3+2\sqrt2)(4+2\sqrt3)=12+8\sqrt2+6\sqrt3+4\sqrt6\implies a=12$$

$$F^4=a^2+b+\sqrt{c+\sqrt d}+2a\sqrt{b+\sqrt{c+\sqrt d}}$$

$$F^4=(3+2\sqrt2)^2(4+2\sqrt3)^2=(17+12\sqrt2)(28+16\sqrt3)$$

$\implies a^2+b=17\cdot28$ but $a=12$

Can you take it home from  here?

Comment: Very very impressed. Thankyou.

Comment: @sub8, My Pleasure. Please let me know if you find a better method

Comment: Aren't you assuming that $8\sqrt2+6\sqrt3+4\sqrt6-\sqrt{b+\sqrt{c+\sqrt d}}$ can't be a nonzero integer?

Comment: @GerryMyerson, I'm assuming that to be zero, else the solution is probably not unique

Comment: So, you are finding *one* solution, but not claiming to find *all* solutions, right?